# Pundit defining current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, pundit

I am building a rails API and I'm using pundit for authorizations to the API. I am trying to define `current_user` for pundit with this method:

```
def pundit_user
  User.find_by_other_means
end
```

I tried implementing it as a private method in my API base controller but it gives me this error:

```
"exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `find_by_other_means' for #<Class:0x00007f9d25463768>\nDid you mean?  find_or_create_by>"
```

Then I tried implementing it on my application controller and it gives me the following error:

```
"exception": "#<NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Api::V1::NewsController:0x00007f9d2516b038>>"
```

How can I define `current_user` in pundit?

Comment: When defining `pundit_user` you have to write your own code for returning your user class - `find_by_other_means` mentioned in the documentation is just a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own `current_user` in `ApplicationController`, or use `pundit_user` - as mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#customize-pundit-user)

Comment: I defined ```pundit_user``` in application controller but it is still giving me the same error